# Add a "show all" button to pagination on WooCommerce product loop

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to add an "see all products" button to the pagnition on product pages.

I'm working from
[Add a “View all” button on WooCommerce product archives pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/333219/79855)

This is what I have:

```
/**
 * This will add a 'Show All' link after the pagination on the shop pages.
 * It will be hidden once it is activated.
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'wpse333192_add_showall', 40 );

function wpse333192_add_showall() {

    if ( ! isset( $_GET['showall'] ) ) {
        global $wp;
echo '<div class="woocommerce-ordering">';
        echo sprintf(
            "<a href='%s'>%s</a>",
            home_url( add_query_arg( array_merge( $_GET, [ 'showall' => 1 ] ), $wp->request ) ),
            __( 'Show All', 'text-domain' )
        );
echo '</div>';  
    }

}

/**
 * This will alter the main product query if 'showall' is activated
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse333192_alter_query_showall' );

function wpse333192_alter_query_showall( $query ) {

    /**
     * Alter the query only if it is:
     * 1. The main query
     * 2. Post type is product
     * 3. $_GET['showall'] is set
     * 4. $_GET['showall'] equals 1
     */
    if ( $query->is_main_query()
         && $query->get( 'post_type' ) == 'product'
         && isset( $_GET['showall'] )
         && $_GET['showall'] == 1
    ) {
        // Load the 'first' page
        $query->set( 'paged', 1 );

        // Set post per page to unlimited
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', - 1 );
    }

    return $query;
}
```

It is not working completely. The button works, but the product count does not change. I need the product page to show all products when the button is clicked.

Comment: I have tested this code, and it works just fine, The product count is changed and correct when "show all" is enabled… So it seems that your issue is related to your theme, an additional plugin or some custom code...

Comment: I've tried the code with 3 different instalations, 1 with no customcode or plugins - none work. I don't get it.

Comment: For me it works just fine on Storefront theme within all last versions of Wordpress and WooCommerce.

Comment: ok, thanks for testing. Tried it on a few more same result. Doesn't actually change the number of products.

Comment: For me for example it displays "Showing 1–12 of 158 results" on start  and when I click show all, it displays "Showing all 158 results"… so it works…